# Error: "Text file busy" while running multiple webdrivers in parallel in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, concurrent.futures

I am using concurrent.futures in python to run multiple chrome-webdrivers in parallel for webscraping. The class "ThreadSafeDriver" initializes and returns a driver for every thread and ensures that the driver is closed properly within the thread.

```
class ThreadSafeDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local = threading.local()

    def initialize_driver(self):
        try:
            if not hasattr(self.local, 'driver'):
                options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                options.add_argument("--headless")
                options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
                options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
                self.local.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        except Exception as error:
            logging.error(error)

    def get_driver(self):
        return self.local.driver

    def close_driver(self):
        if hasattr(self.local, 'driver'):
            try:
                self.local.driver.quit()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)
            finally:
                del self.local.driver
```

This is how i use concurrent.futures:

```
def parallel(self,data):
        try:
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                futures = [executor.submit(self.process_row, row, data) for _, row in data.iterrows()]
                concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
        except Exception as error:
            logging.error(error)
```

When i run the code locally everything works fine, but when i run it within a docker container
i get the following error

> ERROR:root:[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/117.0.5938.88/chromedriver'

The error means that multiple webdrivers try to access the chromedriver file simultaneously.
When i use "max_workers = 1" as an argument everything works fine when running the code within the docker container. Any help is much appreciated

This is the docker build

```
FROM python:3.11.2
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app 
RUN apt -f install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install bzip2 -y && apt-get install unzip -y

RUN wget -q "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.62/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip" \
-O /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
&& unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /usr/local/bin/ \
&& rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt 
RUN python3 -m nltk.downloader punkt

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```